# Optimizing an active record query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a model e.g:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  enum proficiency: [ :novice, :developer, :pro, :legend ]
end
```

The status of a user can change depending on various conditions or events e.g. inactivity for 3 months will decay your proficiency

I am building a mobile app to show me real time analytics. i would like to know what is the most query/memory efficient way for me to get the count of user's in each proficiency level.

I have tried these two methods,

```
# One:
User.novice.count
User.developer.count
User.pro.count
User.legend.count

# Two:
User.group(:proficiency).count
```

How do i optimize this? would partitioning help?

Details about my application :

> rails 5.0.0.rc2 ;
>   pg 0.18 ;
>   Model has ~50million records ;
>   Indexes enabled

Comment: What do you mean, "indexes enabled"? Also show [query plans](https://robots.thoughtbot.com/reading-an-explain-analyze-query-plan) for these queries.

Comment: Rails likes caches, keep in mind this always. If you dnt caching, shame on you :)